# The Content of the StepProgressBar does update even when the state changes

Tags: reactjs, next.js, bootstrap-4

I'm using the package react-step-progress in a NextJs application to create a form that has multi step progress,  with my current implementation,  going to the different steps works fine. The problem is when I want to validate some input fields before going to the next step.

With what I've done so far, I created a state `firstScreenValidated` that holds a boolean value which get passed to the attribute `validated` of the form that act as the content of step 1, when the `firstScreenValidated` is true the form is supposed to show error messages for the required input fields that have not been filled.

When I click on Next button , the validator's function of step 1 is called, for the sake of trying I'm explicitly setting the value of `firstScreenValidated` to true and I'm returning false from the validator so that I can stay on the same step while now viewing the error messages as the attribute `validated` will now have the value true.

But it occurs to me that even when the state `firstScreenValidated` changes value, it never updates the content of the step and the error message specified on the form is never displayed.

Here is my implementation:

```
import Head from 'next/head'
import { Form,Button, Container, Row, Col } from 'react-bootstrap'
import InputGroup from 'react-bootstrap/InputGroup';
import homeStyles from '@/styles/Home.module.css'



import StepProgressBar from 'react-step-progress';
import 'react-step-progress/dist/index.css';


export default function Home() {

  const [firstScreenValidated, setFirstScreenValidated] = useState(false);
 

  const firstScreenValidator = () => {

      setFirstScreenValidated(true); // changing the value to true explicitly
      return false;
      
  }

  return (
    <>
      <Head>
        <meta name="description" content="Generated by create next app" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1.0" />
        <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" />
      </Head>
      <Container fluid>
           <Row className={`${homeStyles.bg_blue}`}  style={{height: '100px'}}><h1>{`${firstScreenValidated}`}</h1></Row>
      </Container>
      <Container>  
            <Row>
              <Col md={2} xs={0}></Col>
              <Col md={8} xs={12} className='bg-light border'>
              
                  <StepProgressBar labelClass={homeStyles.step_label} wrapperClass={homeStyles.step_content}  startingStep={0} onSubmit={()=> console.log("Submitted")} steps={
                       [
                        {
                          label: 'Identity',
                          name: 'step 1',
                          validator: firstScreenValidator,
                       
                          /** Step 1 Content **/
                          content:  <Form id="form_screen_1" noValidate method="POST" validated={firstScreenValidated}>
                                        <h1>{`${firstScreenValidated}`}</h1>
                                        <Row>
                                          <Col>
                                          <Form.Group  className={`my-3 mx-2 ${homeStyles.form_input}`}>
                                              <Form.Label className='fw-bold'>{"full Name"}</Form.Label>
                                                <Form.Control required={true} type="text" className={`${homeStyles.form_input}`} placeholder={"Please Enter your name"}/>
                                                <Form.Control.Feedback type="invalid">{"Please Provide Your full name "}</Form.Control.Feedback>
                                            </Form.Group>
                                          </Col>
                                        </Row>
                                    </Form> , 
                          /** Step 1 Content End **/          
                        
                        },
                        {
                          label: 'Visa',
                          name: 'step 2',
                          content: <SecondScreen />,
                         
                        },
                        {
                          label: 'Upload',
                          name: 'step 3',
                          content: <ThirdScreen />
                          
                        }
                       ]
                  } />
        
              </Col>
              <Col md={2} xs={0}></Col>
            </Row>         
      </Container> 
    </>
  )
}
```

Any guidance to resolve this situation will be greatly appreciated. Thanks